# Eliminacion de registros

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla donde guardo datos que son momentáneos.

Mi pregunta es, ¿se puede hacer un borrado por tiempo, que cada cierto tiempo se borren los datos automáticamente sin necesidad de estar pendiente de eliminarlos manualmente?

No sé si mediante un `trigger` se pueda hacer esto

```
244931  2019-06-15 00:00:00.000
242840  2019-06-04 00:00:00.000
33810   2015-08-20 00:00:00.000
33700   2015-08-13 00:00:00.000
26193   2015-06-16 00:00:00.000
273245  2019-11-19 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Aquí tienes cómo hacerlo con un trigger https://www.the-art-of-web.com/sql/trigger-delete-old/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que lo mejor es tener un procedimiento almacenado que por ejemplo realice un `Truncate table`.

Luego crear un trabajo (job) en el Agente de SQL Server que llame a este procedimiento. Solo te quedará programar el job para que realice el borrado con la frecuencia que quieras.

Si no dispones del SQL Server Agent, por ser la versión Express, puedes utilizar la [utilidad de línea de comandos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) `sqlcmd`. Debes crear un archivo `.cmd`, es decir un archivo de texto con esta extensión que contenga por ejemplo:

`sqlcmd -E -S .\Nombreinstancia -d BaseDeDatos -Q "EXECUTE dbo.ProcedimientoAlmacenado"`

Y creas una tarea en el Programador de Tareas de Windows que ejecute ese `cmd` con la frecuencia que quieras.

Comment: No habia pensado en eso, pero hasta donde tengo entendido los jobs se ejecutan mediante el sql Agent, que pasa si tengo un motor que no contiene esta caracteristica?

Comment: He editado la respuesta para proponer otra solución por si tienes SQL Express

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfecto